# What is the difference between List Definition & List Template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can anyone tell
"What is the Difference between List-Definition & List-Template?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this definition is clear and helpful

List Definition:

A list definition defines a schema for a SharePoint list. It contains information on what views are being used, which columns and content types are being used, and other metadata information.

List Template:

A list template can either be created by end users through the SharePoint user interface using an existing list as a pattern or using an existing list instance. If based on a user-created list it is called a custom list template. A custom list template includes everything that defines the list, including list columns and site columns used by the list, content types used by the list, views defined for the list, and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose we create 2 lists. One from list template and another list from list definition. Then does modification to the list def or list template get inherited by the list instance?

Answer (score 1):

**List Definition:** Its a simple xml file that holds the definitions(or more precisely declarations) for the schema, content types , columns and views that will make up a list in SharePoint.

**List Template:** Template refers to the packaging of an existing list instance including its definitions and content into a SharePoint compatible reusable file that can be moved from one sharepoint site to another. Think of it in a way where a single table in a database has been exported along with its content in a executable sql script that can be reused across any other database.

Comment: Suppose we create 2 lists. One from list template and another list from list definition. Then does modification to the list def or list template get inherited by the list instance?